# How to improve Kudu reads with Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kudu, apache-kudu

I have a process that given a new input retrieves related information form our Kudu database and then does some computation.

The problem lies in the data retrieval, we have **1.201.524.092 rows** and for any computation, it takes forever to start processing the needed ones because the reader needs to give it all to spark.

To read form kudu we do:

```
def read(tableName: String): Try[DataFrame] = {
        val kuduOptions: Map[String, String] = Map(
                "kudu.table" -> tableName,
                "kudu.master" -> kuduContext.kuduMaster)
        
        SQLContext.read.options(kuduOptions).format("kudu").load
        
}
```

And then:

```
val newInputs = ??? // Dataframe with the new inputs
val currentInputs = read("inputsTable") // This takes too much time!!!!

val relatedCurrent = currentInputs.join(newInputs.select("commonId", Seq("commonId"), "inner")

doThings(newInputs, relatedCurrent)
```

For example, we only want to introduce a single new input. Well, it has to scan the full table to find the *currentInputs* which makes a Shuffle Write of 81.6 GB / 1201524092 rows.

How can I improve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the new input and after that you can use it in a where clause.
Using this way you can easily hit an OOM, but it can make your query very fast because it's going to benefit of predicate pushdown

```
val collectedIds = newInputs.select("commonId").collect
val filtredCurrentInputs = currentInputs.where($"commonId".isin(collectedIds))
```